# C# WinForms Размер приложения и потребление ОЗУ

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

**C# WinForms Размер приложения и потребление ОЗУ**

Почему так происходит и как это исправить? При написании легкого приложения, где используются 3 формы всего и пару переменных, для счетчика (таймера типа), приложение весит *~30 КБ*, а занимает ОЗУ *начиная от ~13 МБ и доходит до ~24 МБ*.

Аналогичное приложение с большим, даже очень большим функционалом для своего жанра приложение весит *~300 КБ*, а занимает ОЗУ *начиная от ~4 МБ и доходит до ~13 МБ*. Написано это приложение тоже на C#.

Есть еще 1 приложение уже функционал меньше, меньше моего приложения, весит *~1 МБ*, а занимает ОЗУ *начиная от ~2 МБ и доходит до ~4 МБ*. Приложение написано не  на C#, а на чем-то другом, возможно Delphi или Lazarus.

**Объясните почему так и как это исправить? Из-за чего так происходит и возможно на чем тогда писать (какой язык), чтобы было ООП (GUI, IDE).**

Comment: 13 мегабайт? Это практически 0. Очень хорошо, у вас реально нетребовательная к ресурсам программа.

Comment: Помоему ответ прост: приложение на C# загружает в процесс библиотеки CLR, а приложение на Delphi - нет. Используйте любой отладчик, чтобы посмотреть, какие библиотеки загружает приложение, тогда все станет ясно.

Comment: Да, я знаю что цифры ерунда, ну просто для такого легкого приложения должно мало ресов брать, я привел похожие программы, но там функционал ого-го, особенно который на c#. Также если сравнивать с другими программами, они тоже мало потребляют (к примеру возьмем aida64, это так к примеру), также launcher игр там используется графика (физуальные эффекты), функционал и берет оно мало

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CLR (Common Language Runtime) при старте выделяет с запасом пул памяти вашему приложению. Благодаря этому, память в дальнейшем выделяется очень быстро под ваши объекты.

Если очень хочется, можно отобрать у приложения лишнюю непотребляемую в данный момент память.

Для этого можно использовать WinAPI-функцию [SetProcessWorkingSetSize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms686234(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


// Объявляем её
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool SetProcessWorkingSetSize(IntPtr hProcess,
    int dwMinimumWorkingSetSize, int dwMaximumWorkingSetSize);


// Вызываем в том месте, где хотим уменьшить потребление памяти.
// Например, сразу после старта приложения.
SetProcessWorkingSetSize(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle, -1, -1);
```

Естественно, когда программе понадобится больше памяти, она опять будет выделена.

Однако, это всё бессмысленные действия. Позвольте системе самой определять, сколько памяти нужно.

---

Дополню. Много памяти выделяется для того, чтобы приложение работало быстрее. При этом остальные приложения и система в целом не страдают: как только им станет не хватать памяти, ОС отнимет излишки у вашего приложения. А когда вы сами ограничиваете своё приложение в памяти, вы ухудшаете его производительность.

Это распространённый приём программирования: размен памяти на производительность.

Comment: Спасибо, вроде помогло, добавил в загрузку формы и стало потреблять меньше, в отличии до этого, когда от _13 МБ_ доходило до _24 МБ_ в течении времени

Answer (score 3):

1. Приведенные вами цифры не являются существенными ни для современных систем,  ни для систем 10-15 летней давности (для PC разумеется). Панику нужно поднимать когда потребление ресурсов постоянно и необоснованно растет - это явный признак проблем в коде. В противном случае все это преждевременные оптимизации.
2. Размер файлов приложения на диске ни как не связан с используемой оперативной памятью. Причин для этого много: приложение может и использует ресурсы операционной системы, которые уже находятся в памяти; в процессе работы приложение может генерировать данные, на которые будет выделяться дополнительная память в процессе работы; дополнительный расход памяти может быть связан с особенностями конкретной среды исполнения вашего приложения.
3. Любой удобный для человека язык добавляет накладные расходы на потребляемые ресурсы. Это неизбежная цена за комфорт как разработки, так и дальнейшего использования. Хотите минимизировать использование ресурсов вашим приложением - откажитесь от графических рюшечек, пишите на ассемблере с использованием максимально доступных оптимизаций компилятора. Может и получится круто, но затраты времени и необходимый уровень знаний выйдут на околоземную орбиту, а полезность для конечного пользователя будет все еще под большим вопросом. Когда выбираете на чем писать - выбирайте исходя из наличия и возможностей стандартных (или широко известных) библиотек и фреймворков, а также уровня ваших знаний, универсального правильного на 100% варианта не существует.

Ну и последнее. Оценивайте используемые ресурсы после компиляции в режиме `Release` и запуске без VisualStudio. В `Debug`-режиме не используются некоторые оптимизации компилятора и студия имеет привычку вмешиваться в процесс работы приложения для обеспечения возможностей отладки, поэтому приложение всегда потребляет больше, чем ему на самом делен нужно.

Comment: Да, я знаю что цифры ерунда, ну просто для такого легкого приложения должно мало ресов, я привел похожие программы, но там функционал ого-го, особенно который на c#. Также если сравнивать с другими программами, они тоже мало потребляют (к примеру возьмем aida64, это так к примеру), также launcher игр там используется графика (физуальные эффекты), функционал и берет оно мало. Насчет, запуска, я запускал го без студии, но DEBUG , щас попробовал RELEASE, там какое-то окошко выскочило и я нажал "только мой код", теперь это окошечко не выскакивает, я правильно нажал? а то там было с отладкой еще

Comment: @user287413 ну по фразе "какое-то окошечко" сложно угадать что именно у вас спрашивали при запуске. Но факт остается фактом, когда запускаешь проект даже в релизе из студии, студия добавляет некоторый служебный код. Так что тут ровно также, как при измерении скорости - хотите настоящие цифры, собирайте в релиз, глушите студию и  запускайте средствами ОС.